# How to make bar charts shorter with ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I basically have a very simple question, how can I make bar charts shorter? If I search for it on the web I can only find "width", but this is not what I want. I want to make the lenght of the bars shorter.

```
library(ggplot2)

# data
data <- data.frame(
  name=c("A","B","C","D","E") ,
  value=c(3,12,5,18,45)
)

# bar chart
ggplot(data, aes(x=name, y=value)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", width=0.8) +
  coord_flip()
```

I basically just want that the lenght of the bar goes up to like around 20, so somehow just half the length..

Comment: You could divide data$value by 2 just as you proposed? Since the max value is 45 and your are looking to reduce the height but maintain the information this would be the best solution. Otherwise you can subtract 25 from each element of data$value but that will result in negative values... Or you could reduce all values above 20 to 20 but then you loose information depending on your goal

Comment: The bars go as far as the data dictates... to

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean how do you make the bars visibly shorter on the page without affecting their numerical representation. Perhaps you just need to set the axis limits?

If your plot looks like this...

```r
p <- ggplot(data, aes(x=name, y=value)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", width=0.8) +
  coord_flip()
p
```

[image]

Then you can just do this...

```r
p + scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 2 * max(data$value)))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-11-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: ok, this seems a good solution. there is just one thing: I would like to cut the diagram at the value of 50. how to do this? basically I want the same diagram as in the initial example but a bit compressed...

Comment: @titeuf then you need to change the dimensions of the plotting window. Just drag the window so it is narrower. Simple as that.